# Finding the second level keys of a multi key dictionary Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multi key dict in the following format. I am trying to access the list of the second level keys, however, it is returning the keys in the format of a dict_keys list. What I am trying to get is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

```
dictTest={}
dictTest[1]={'a':1, 'b':2}
dictTest[2]={'c':1, 'd':2}
dictTest[3]={'e':1, 'f':2}
print(dictTest)
print(list([dictTest[i].keys() for i in dictTest.keys()]))         
{1: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 2: {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, 3: {'e': 1, 'f': 2}}
[dict_keys(['a', 'b']), dict_keys(['c', 'd']), dict_keys(['e', 'f'])]
```

Comment: What if the same key appears more than once?

Comment: `[k for d in dictTest.values() for k in d.keys()]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# sum([list(b.keys()) for b in dictTest.values()], [])
# syntax improvement by @wwii
sum([list(b) for b in dictTest.values()], [])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: sum is a great idea, nice work! probably more efficient than my approach as well

Comment: @jab I don't think so, this is just for short syntax, I think itertools chain will be much faster for larger dictionaries.

Comment: `...[list(b) for b in dictTest.values()]...`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.chain` in combination with mapping `dict.keys` to all the dicts values:

```
from itertools import chain

dictTest = {1: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 2: {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, 3: {'e': 1, 'f': 2}}

print(list(chain(*map(dict.keys, dictTest.values()))))
```

---

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> [v2 for v1 in dictTest.values() for v2 in v1]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```